# Why are my legs still sore/untested?

Tags: legs, muscle-soreness, post-workout

Last night I did a bunch of calisthenic squats and now that it's the morning, my legs still feel like the way they felt right after the workout, weak and wobbly

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28646/weakness-in-shoulder-a-few-days-after-archery-why-did-i-get-weaker-why/28653#28653

Answer (score 1):

If you read about DOMS or [Delayed onset muscle soreness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_onset_muscle_soreness) I think you'll find a lot of the information that you're looking for. Your body generally needs a few weeks to become accustomed to exercise that it isn't used to. It'll be the worst initially, then tone down over the course of those weeks, until it's much less noticeable.

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid eccentric contraction, which mostly cause muscle soreness, for the first couple of days of exercise, do concentric and get help for eccentric part. It will help a lot :-) Enjoy